# Define a dynamic matrix with EIGEN

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, matrix, eigen

I have a problem with this code, the main idea is to create a typedef 'Base' with the number of cols defined in the template:

```
// --- Row dynamic matrix
template< class T, int cols >
class RowDynamicMatrixRowMajor : public Eigen::Matrix< T, Eigen::Dynamic, cols,
      Eigen::RowMajor | Eigen::AutoAlign >{
public:
  typedef Eigen::Matrix< T, Eigen::Dynamic, cols, Eigen::RowMajor | Eigen::AutoAlign > Base;

  RowDynamicMatrixRowMajor( void ) : Base()
  {}
  template< typename OtherDerived >
  RowDynamicMatrixRowMajor( const Eigen::MatrixBase< OtherDerived > & other )
      : Base( other )
  {}
  template< typename OtherDerived >
  RowDynamicMatrixRowMajor & operator= ( const Eigen::MatrixBase< OtherDerived > & other )
  {
    this->Base::operator=( other );
    return *this;
  }
};
```

But, when compile the code in visual studio 2012, I get this error:

Error   1   error C2975: '_Cols' : invalid template argument for 'Eigen::Matrix'; expected compile-time constant expression z:\desktop\photoconsistency-visual-odometry-master\phovo\include\Matrix.h   97  1   PhotoconsistencyVisualOdometry

For the file, there are 20 similar errors, but I cannot identify the mistake.

Comment: You're not showing us the real source of the error.  I don't see `_Cols` declared anywhere in the code you posted.

Comment: I believe that the variable _Cols in the error is related with the definition of Eigen:Matrix :

template<typename _Scalar, int _Rows, int _Cols, int _Options, int _MaxRows, int _MaxCols>

class Eigen::Matrix< _Scalar, _Rows, _Cols, _Options, _MaxRows, _MaxCols >

so, in this case _Cols is cols, but I'm not really sure about this.

Answer (score 2):

I can compile and run this without any issue (g++ 4.9), so this is not the source of the error. Although this is not an answer, I posted as I cannot post code in a comment.

```
template< class T, int cols >
class RowDynamicMatrixRowMajor : public Eigen::Matrix< T, Eigen::Dynamic, cols, 
      Eigen::RowMajor | Eigen::AutoAlign >
{
public:
  typedef Eigen::Matrix< T, Eigen::Dynamic, cols, Eigen::RowMajor | Eigen::AutoAlign > Base;

  RowDynamicMatrixRowMajor( void ) : Base()
  {}
  template< typename OtherDerived >
  RowDynamicMatrixRowMajor( const Eigen::MatrixBase< OtherDerived > & other )
      : Base( other )
  {}
  template< typename OtherDerived >
  RowDynamicMatrixRowMajor & operator= ( const Eigen::MatrixBase< OtherDerived > & other )
  {
    this->Base::operator=( other );
    return *this;
  }
};

int main()
{
    RowDynamicMatrixRowMajor<double, 10> a;     
}
```

As a side remark, are you sure you want to derive from Eigen? 
http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicCustomizingEigen.html

I find it much much simpler to typedef what I need (you need C++11 support for template aliases), e.g. in your case:

```
template<typename Scalar, int cols> // Eigen::MatrixX<type> (where type = Scalar)
using RowDynamicMatrixRowMajor = 
      Eigen::Matrix<Scalar, Eigen::Dynamic, cols, Eigen::RowMajor | Eigen::AutoAlign>;
```

then use it as e.g.

```
RowDynamicMatrixRowMajor<double, 10> a;
```